# Matlab - Finding probability of event occurring within specific distance

Tags: matlab, probability

I'm new to Matlab and I would some help with a simulation. I'm creating an experiment where I have to determine the number of random insertion events in order for one insertion to occur within 15 units of a reference point out of a 3300 unit area. The insertions have an equal probability of occurring anywhere within the 3300 units. I would like for there to be a greater than 50% chance that at least one insertion occurs within the 15 units of the reference point.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and what specific issues you're having.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need MATLAB for this.

Have E[num IP within 15 units of RP] = E[num IP per unit sq] * pi * 15^2 ~= 801.1 E[num IP per unit sq] = 801.1/3300 density ~= 0.2428 density
So P(at least one IP within 15 units of RP) = 1 - P(zero IP within 15 units of RP) = 1 - e^(-E[num IP within 15 units of RP]) = 1 - e^(-0.2428 density) = 1 - 1.275^(-density)

So for P(at least one IP within 15 units of RP) = 0.5, 1.275^density = 2 so density ~= 2.855 and E[num IP per unit sq] ~= 0.0008652